# How to show sidebar differently to 2 different user roles in React?

Tags: reactjs, router, roles, sidebar

In my React project, I access the dashboard with 2 different users, admin and restaurant. I want to hide some of the headers in the sidebar. The titles that the Admin user and the Restaurant user should see should be different. (compatible with router v6)

routes.js

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home' },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    element: Dashboard,
  },
  {
    path: '/foundation',
    name: 'Foundation',
    element: Foundation,
  },
]
```

_nav.js

```
const _nav = [
  {
    component: CNavItem,
    name: 'Dashboard',
    to: '/dashboard',
    icon: <CIcon icon={cilSpeedometer} customClassName="nav-icon" />,
    badge: {
      color: 'info',
    },
  },
  {
    component: CNavItem,
    name: 'Mekan',
    to: '/foundation',
    icon: <CIcon icon={cilHome} customClassName="nav-icon" />,
    badge: {
      color: 'info',
    },
  },
]
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Suspense fallback={loading}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="*" name="Home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
      <ToastContainer></ToastContainer>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```